# Not able to add Multiple Markers in GSMapView xCode Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

I am trying to add multiple Markers on Googlemaps in my app.

In the viewcontrolller under viewDidLoad I am able to load the map and a single marker.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = NSLocalizedString("section_map", comment: "test")
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 48.7784, longitude:9.18121, zoom: 12)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)


    view = mapView
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

    mapView.delegate = self

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.7784,longitude: 9.18121)
    marker.title = "title"
    marker.snippet = "snipple"
    marker.icon = UIImage(named:"pin_you")
    marker.map = mapView

    mapData()
}
```

It call mapData() and from there is json file is generated 
after parsing setPin is called to set the markers

```
  func setPin(){


    DispatchQueue.main.async {

       for item in self.mapItems {
           print (" \(item.name)  \(item.marker) \(item.latitude) \(item.longitude)")

           let marker = GMSMarker()
           marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item.latitude,longitude: item.longitude)
           marker.title = item.name
           marker.snippet = item.fulladdress

           var iconImage: String
           switch (item.marker){
           case 1:
              iconImage = "pin_silver"
           case 2:
              iconImage = "pin_blue"
           case 3:
              iconImage = "pin_gold"
           case 6:
              iconImage = "pin_you"
           default:
              iconImage = "pin_silver"
           }
           marker.icon = UIImage(named:iconImage)
           marker.map = self.mapView


       }

    }
}
```

The pins are not shown.

The print in **for item in self.mapItems** shows

```
Position number A  1 48.76947562 9.15440351
Position number B  1 48.75716485 9.17081058
Position number C  1 48.81191625 9.22752149
Position number D  2 48.81192516 9.22766708
```

this means all the proper data is available. 
However the map is there the one pin made in viewDidLoad
The Markers in function setPin are not shown or maybe not set.

Does any-one have an idea?

Comment: Can you tell me 
self.mapView
Where it is declared?

Comment: Can you please cross check if self.mapView is properly initialized.

I saw you have initialized locally this below:-
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)

And you must be having a map view object outside viewDidLoad function at the top.
That particular map object needs to be initialized and configured properly.

Comment: @Manish Pathak.I have this just after the mapViewController: UIViewController { (at)IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

Comment: mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera) remove let in view did load for this initialization

Comment: You don't have to create object of mapview again in view did load method just remove let from their

Comment: i have remove let (    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)) now I don't get a map at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in have changed the mapData(mapView: GMSMapView!) also for setPin(mapView: GMSMapView!)

```
  func setpin(mapView: GMSMapView!){


    DispatchQueue.main.async {

       for item in self.mapItems {
           print (" \(item.name)  \(item.marker) \(item.latitude) \(item.longitude)")

           let marker = GMSMarker()
           marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item.latitude,longitude: item.longitude)
           marker.title = item.name
           marker.snippet = item.fulladdress

           var iconImage: String
           switch (item.marker){
           case 1:
              iconImage = "pin_silver"
           case 2:
              iconImage = "pin_blue"
           case 3:
              iconImage = "pin_gold"
           case 6:
              iconImage = "pin_you"
           default:
              iconImage = "pin_silver"
           }
           marker.icon = UIImage(named:iconImage)
           marker.map = mapView


       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Clustering your markers**, you can put a large number of markers on a map without making the map hard to read. The marker clustering utility helps you manage multiple markers at different zoom levels.

For the full code sample, see the ObjCDemoApp and SwiftDemoApp on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils).

To add a simple marker clusterer.

```
/// Point of Interest Item which implements the GMUClusterItem protocol.
class POIItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
  var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  var name: String!

  init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String) {
    self.position = position
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

The following code creates a cluster manager using the GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm and the MUDefaultClusterRenderer that are included in the utility library:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMUClusterManagerDelegate,
GMSMapViewDelegate {

   private var mapView: GMSMapView!
   private var clusterManager: GMUClusterManager!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up the cluster manager with the supplied icon generator and
    // renderer.
    let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
    let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
    let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView,
                            clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
    clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm,
                                                  renderer: renderer)

    // Generate and add random items to the cluster manager.
    generateClusterItems()

    // Call cluster() after items have been added to perform the clustering
    // and rendering on map.
     clusterManager.cluster()
  }
}
```

Feed your markers into the cluster as GMUClusterItem objects by calling clusterManager:addItem:. The following code randomly generates cluster items (POIs) within the scope of the map's camera, then feeds them to the cluster manager:

```
/// Randomly generates cluster items within some extent of the camera and
/// adds them to the cluster manager.
private func generateClusterItems() {
  let extent = 0.2
   for index in 1...kClusterItemCount {
    let lat = kCameraLatitude + extent * randomScale()
    let lng = kCameraLongitude + extent * randomScale()
    let name = "Item \(index)"
    let item =
    POIItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng), name: name)
    clusterManager.addItem(item)
  }
}

 /// Returns a random value between -1.0 and 1.0.
 private func randomScale() -> Double {
   return Double(arc4random()) / Double(UINT32_MAX) * 2.0 - 1.0
}
```

Handle events on markers and clusters

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMUClusterManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

  private var mapView: GMSMapView!
  private var clusterManager: GMUClusterManager!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    // ... Rest of code omitted for easy reading.

    // Register self to listen to both GMUClusterManagerDelegate and
    // GMSMapViewDelegate events.
    clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
  }

  // MARK: - GMUClusterManagerDelegate

  func clusterManager(clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTapCluster cluster: GMUCluster) {
    let newCamera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(cluster.position,
  zoom: mapView.camera.zoom + 1)
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(newCamera)
    mapView.moveCamera(update)
  }

   // MARK: - GMUMapViewDelegate

  func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    if let poiItem = marker.userData as? POIItem {
       NSLog("Did tap marker for cluster item \(poiItem.name)")
    } else {
       NSLog("Did tap a normal marker")
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

For more Details please follow the [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering#add-a-simple-marker-clusterer)